# Swipe view like SnapChat

Tags: swift, swipe, gif, ios8

I'm doing this :

```
    self.addChildViewController(blackView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(blackView.view)
    blackView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

But the code works even If I only do

```
    self.scrollView.addSubview(blackView.view)
```

So I was wondering if ignoring the first and last line would be a problem for the app?

Answer (score 0):

Calling those methods allows the `blackView` controller to go through the `UIViewController` lifecycle properly like calling `viewWillAppear:',`viewDidappear:`, etc.

You can even add `willMoveToParentViewController`:

```
self.addChildViewController(blackView)
self.scrollView.addSubview(blackView.view)
blackView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

If you're removing a controller, you have to do a similar process:

```
blackView.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
blackView.view.removeFromSuperview
blackView.removeFromParentViewController
```

[That link](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers) explains it too, with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nice example here in Objective-C:

> https://github.com/devenergy/SpinKit-ObjC/tree/master/Demo/SpinKit

Some code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;

UIView *panel1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(screenBounds, screenWidth * index, 0.0)];
[scrollView addSubview:panel1];

UIView *panel2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(screenBounds, screenWidth * index, 0.0)];
[scrollView addSubview:panel2];
```